# I am trying to use webjars in spring boot, but I get ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, webjars

I tried to use `Webjars` to use `jQuery` in my `spring boot project`.

However, `jQuery` didn't work and I checked it by pressing `F12`.

> GET http: // localhost: 8100 / webjars / jquery / 3.4.1 / jquery.min.js net :: ERR_ABORTED 404

First I added `Webjars` to `pom.xml`.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>0.30</version>
    </dependency> -->
</dependencies>
```

And in the `html header` part I added:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("Hello~!?");
});
</script>
```

As you can see from the `pom.xml` code above, I tried using `webjars-locator`, but again I got the same error.

When I used `webjars-locator` I deleted the version name and used it.

What was the problem even though it was listed at https://www.webjars.org/documentation#springboot?

Comment: I found this article [baeldung-maven-webjars](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-webjars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell spring where will be your `js` lib files.

By default when you use webjars, all lib are added in `webjars` folder

So you need to add this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    }
}
```

or in XML

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
```

And `webjars-locator` will find library on the classpath and use it to automatically resolve the version of any `WebJars` assets. This works for Spring ver >= 4.2

Now you can use it in HTML like this

```
<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

4y later with Spring boot starter 3.2.0

I had forgotten to add this dependency to the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```